# Minimize Windows Live 2012 to Windows 8 system tray in desktop mode?

Tags: windows-8, notification-area, windows-live-mail

I want to run Windows live 2012 in system tray, so that it can run without having an instance on taskbar when minimized. This was possible with Windows 7 by running Windows Live Mail 2011 in compatibility mode for Vista SP2, but now if this is attempted in Windows 8 on the newer software, everything crashes. Is there anything that can be done, please?!

Comment: I don't believe so. Unless you find a way to pick a task bar element and make it invisible, like you can by pressing the notification area's up arrow.

Comment: See if any of these help: [RBTray](http://moitah.net), [4t Tray Minimizer](http://www.4t-niagara.com/tray.html), [Actual Window Minimizer](http://goo.gl/E92x8) ... (just search the net for similar programs if these don't do the trick).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Powermenu](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-minimize-an-application-to-system-tray-in-windows/). It can minimize anything (yes, anything) to the system tray.

Comment: @Robert G. Koharchik any updates on how this solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with [Trayconizer](http://www.whitsoftdev.com/trayconizer/).

Instructions: [Minimize Apps to the System Tray with Trayconizer - How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2651/minimize-apps-to-the-system-tray-with-trayconizer/)

Then you can just change the icon and the way WLM is shown in the task bar (to avoid it showing up twice).